# Please help - how to parse this xml in android - always error

Tags: android, listview, xml-parsing

This is the xml file:
http://dating.rs/nemanja/WebService/getPlaces.php?lat=44.8061999&lon=20.4595333&rad=3502&tfs=0

```
<places>
  <place>
    <id>
      6
    </id>
    <name>
      McDonalds
    </name>
    <type>
      Fast Food
    </type>
    <longitude>
      20.4658031097
    </longitude>
    <latitude>
      44.80228031097
    </latitude>
  </place>
  <place>
    <id>
      5
    </id>
    <name>
      Pizza hut
    </name>
    <type>
      Fast Food
    </type>
    <longitude>
      20.47832518815
    </longitude>
    <latitude>
      44.792844714
    </latitude>
  </place>
</places>
```

This is my code:

```
public class ShopList {

    private ArrayList<String> id = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> type = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> latitude = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> longitude = new ArrayList<String>();

with get i set metods...

public class ReturnPlaces extends DefaultHandler {

    Boolean currentElement = false;
    String currentValue = null;
    public static ShopList shopList = null;

    public static ShopList getShopList(){
        return shopList;
    }

    public static void setShopList(ShopList shopList) {
        ReturnPlaces.shopList = shopList;
    }



    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        if (currentElement) {
            currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
            currentElement = false;
        }

        //super.characters(ch, start, length);
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        currentElement = false;
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("id"))
            shopList.setId(currentValue);
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("name"))
            shopList.setName(currentValue);
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("type"))
            shopList.setType(currentValue);
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("latitude"))
            shopList.setLatitude(currentValue);
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("longitude"))
            shopList.setLongitude(currentValue);        
        //super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {        
        currentElement = true;
        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("place")){
            shopList = new ShopList();
        }else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
            String id1 = attributes.getValue("id");
            shopList.setId(id1);
        }else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
            String name1 = attributes.getValue("name");
            shopList.setName(name1);
        }else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("type")) {
            String type1 = attributes.getValue("type");
            shopList.setType(type1);
        }else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("latitude")) {
            String latitude1 = attributes.getValue("latitude");
            shopList.setLatitude(latitude1);
        }else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("longitude")) {
            String longitude1 = attributes.getValue("longitude");
            shopList.setLatitude(longitude1);
        }
        //super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);
    }

and this is my activity:

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {     
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.pretraga);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView1);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapController = mapView.getController();        
        mapController.setZoom(17);
        mapView.setStreetView(true);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        final double niz [] = i.getDoubleArrayExtra("Trenutna lokacija");
        double lat = niz [0];
        double lng = niz [1];
        int radius = i.getIntExtra("Radius", 501);
        boolean vreme = i.getBooleanExtra("Radno vreme", false);        

        try{
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

            URL sourceUrl = new URL("http://dating.rs/nemanja/WebService/getPlaces.php?lat=44.8061999&lon=20.4595333&rad=3502&tfs=0");
            ReturnPlaces returnPlacesHandler = new ReturnPlaces();
            xr.setContentHandler(returnPlacesHandler);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML parsing exception"+e);
        }

        shopList = ReturnPlaces.getShopList();

        for(int u = 0; u<shopList.getId().size();u++){
            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            float distance;                     
            map.put("name", shopList.getName().get(u));
            map.put("type", shopList.getType().get(u));         
            myList.add(map);            
        }

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this.getApplicationContext(), myList,R.layout.listview1, new String[]{"name","type"},
                new int[]{R.id.textViewName,R.id.textViewType});

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might help you.

//Main Class

```
public class Place extends ListActivity 
{

HashMap<String, String> map;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.placelist);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> accountlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    String xml = XMLParser.getXML();
    Log.i("Retrieved Xml", xml);
    Document doc = XMLParser.parse(xml);

    //Parsing data directly from the XML
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("place");

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) 
    {                           
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();    

        Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
        map.put("id", XMLParser.getValue(e, "id"));
            map.put("name", XMLParser.getValue(e, "name"));

        accountlist.add(map);           
    }       

    ListAdapter adapter = new PlaceAdapter(this, accountlist , R.layout.main, 
                    new String[] { "id", "name" }, 
                    new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.name });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

     final ListView lv = getListView();
     lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true); 
     lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
     {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {               

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);   

            Intent intent = new Intent(Place.this, Results.class); 
            Bundle b = new Bundle();

            b.putString("name",  o.get("name"));
        b.putString("id",  o.get("id"));

            intent.putExtras(b);    
            startActivity(intent); 
        }
    });
}

//Place-Adapter

public class PlaceAdapter extends SimpleAdapter 
{

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> results;

    public PlaceAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) 
    {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        this.results = data;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        int[] colors = new int[] {0x30ffffff, 0x30ff2020, 0x30808080};

      View v = super.getView(position, view, parent);


        if (v == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
        }

        TextView id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id);
        id.setText(results.get(position).get("id"));

        TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setText(results.get(position).get("Name"));

        int colorPos = position % colors.length;
        v.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);

        return v;
    }
}   }
```

//Parsing

```
 public class XMLParser {



public final static Document XMLfromString(String xml){



    Document doc = null;



    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    try {



        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();



        InputSource is = new InputSource();

        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));

        doc = db.parse(is); 



    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {

        System.out.println("XML parse error: " + e.getMessage());

        return null;

    } catch (SAXException e) {

        System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());

        return null;

    } catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.println("I/O exeption: " + e.getMessage());

        return null;

    }



    return doc;



}



/** Returns element value

  * @param elem element (it is XML tag)

  * @return Element value otherwise empty String

  */

 public final static String getElementValue( Node elem ) {

     Node kid;

     if( elem != null){

         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){

             for( kid = elem.getFirstChild(); kid != null; kid = kid.getNextSibling() ){

                 if( kid.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){

                     return kid.getNodeValue();

                 }

             }

         }

     }

     return "";

 }



 public static String getXML(){  

        String line = null;



        try {



            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://dating.rs/nemanja/WebService/getPlaces.php?lat=44.8061999&lon=20.4595333&rad=3502&tfs=0");



            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);



        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";

        } catch (IOException e) {

            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";

        }



        return line;



}



public static int numResults(Document doc){     

    Node results = doc.getDocumentElement();

    int res = -1;



    try{

        res = Integer.valueOf(results.getAttributes().getNamedItem("count").getNodeValue());

    }catch(Exception e ){

        res = -1;

    }



    return res;

}



public static String getValue(Element item, String str) {       

    NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        

    return XMLParser.getElementValue(n.item(0));

}
```

}

//Displaying Reults on click of listview

```
public class Results extends Activity 
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.results);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String id = b.getString("id");
    String name = b.getString("name");

    EditText aid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eid);
    EditText aname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ename);

    aid.setText(id);
    aname.setText(name);
}
```

}

Comment: Wow man...thanks...this is great...i run my app, but this is the full answer...Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

You should not be making URL connections in `onCreate`. This is discouraged in earlier Android versions and is enforced by the framework as of Honeycomb. You need to use a worker thread or (equivalently, but easier) an AsyncTask. See the [Painless Threading blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html) in the Android docs.

Comment: This is not a solution and should be a comment.

Comment: How is this not a solution? If OP's code runs under Honeycomb, it will get a [`NetworkOnMainThreadException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). On earlier versions it is likely to generate an ANR error. Moving to an AsyncTask as recommended will solve these problems. OP gave no indication that the problem was with the parsing itself, just "always error". My guess is that it's due to doing networking on the main thread.

Comment: I make URL connection with this code and getURL metod in ReturnPlaces, but i deleted that, because i wanted to reduce the code here...
Intent i = getIntent();
        final double niz [] = i.getDoubleArrayExtra("Trenutna lokacija");
        double lat = niz [0];
        double lng = niz [1];
        int radius = i.getIntExtra("Radius", 501);
        boolean vreme = i.getBooleanExtra("Radno vreme", false);

Comment: It also now shows only one store in the listView and that is wrong store...but now I dont have any error...its compiled now and app is runing... Sorry for my english :)

Comment: Glad your program is running. Can you mark this question as solved?

Comment: How can i do that? I'm new here and in android :)

Comment: If one of the answers here solved your problem, click on the check mark next to the answer. If you solved your problem on your own, and the way you did it might help someone else, then post your own answer and after it is posted click on the check mark next to that. You can only accept answers to your own questions. Once you have 15 reputation, you can up-vote helpful questions and answers by clicking on the arrow above the vote count to the left of each post. You can vote on questions and answers from anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Dom` `xml` parsing , [see this sample here](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-%E2%80%93-using-domparser)

[and download this sample too](http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/XMLParsing-Using-DOM.zip)